# How to get exact permission using get-acl powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have issue with one script that uses get-acl in powershell and exports it to file.
What i am trying to do is to export all permissions from fileserver that are having isinherited flag Flase. This part works perfectly, but i am getting only allow or deny types on those folders. What i need is to know exact permission for given folder. Does that user has allow Read or Write, Execute etc. Here is whole code for what i have done:

```
$OutFile = "C:\install\powershell\Permissions.txt"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "C:\install\powershell\"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){ 
$ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access } 
Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){ 
if ($ACL.IsInherited -eq $false){ 
$OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags 
Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile 
}}}
```

So my question is: How can i add $ACL. to get exact permission level. Is it even possible?
How can i get some kind of list of Object that i can use parsing ACL`s?
I`m sorry if i have explained my issue wrong or it has been answered already but since today is my 1st day using powershell i might not know how to search for answer correctly.

Best regards.

UPD: It seems i can try to play with $ACL.FileSystemRights i will update this post if it gives me what i want.
UPD2: Yes it seems i had to add FileSystemRights in $Header and " + $ACL.FileSystemRights + " in $OutInfo 
Sorry for disturbing! But mightbe this will help someone get what they need! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [user account "effective permissions" with powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816735/user-account-effective-permissions-with-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

was looking to set recurse to certain levels deep.
Found a solution: instead of using -recurse, use "*".
for 2 levels deep: "**" and so on.
source: http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/11663/25754.aspx

Thanx.

Comment: Links to answers can change over time.  Can you document the relevant code here for your potential solution?